# How to change what saves into DB from send::mail - "Laravel 5.6"

Tags: php, laravel

This might be a very basic question, however I've started working with Laravel and just started on a new project for a company and they already have some code written out like the following below:

```
                        Mail::send('Emails.Home.Orders', $data, function ($message) use ($Orders) {
                            $message->from("donotreply@example.co.uk", "example");
                            $message->to($email);
                            $message->subject("Confirmed Email");
                        });
```

When the above is execute it's saved into database table `email_log` and for the life of me I can't seem to figure out what is calling the DB insert as I've done a global search for `EMAIL` which is the model name for `email_log`.

Does anybody have ideas what could be calling the DB insert in Laravel?

Comment: could you check the user `model` or the model that this email comes from about method called `boot`?

Comment: @Joseph - Looks like it's this package which is imported `https://github.com/shvetsgroup/laravel-email-database-log` which is doing it. What would be the best way to override this?

Comment: it looks that it hasn't this ability to configure it but you could fork it and edit this file as your needs https://github.com/shvetsgroup/laravel-email-database-log/blob/master/src/ShvetsGroup/LaravelEmailDatabaseLog/EmailLogger.php

Comment: @Joseph can you override a package event without changing the package itself in laravel?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: @Joseph - No worries, I will probably remove package and just write my own provider